# Troubles with JSON data and Unicode on django-rest-framework

Tags: json, python-requests, django-rest-framework

I made a REST API with djangorestframework=2.3.14 and client using python requests=2.3.0 and nap=1.0.1. The client sends JSON data to the API with something like that :

```
response = self.environment_detail_url.patch(data=json.dumps({'egg_list': finder.get_eggs_dict()}), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

In REST API view i use this Serializer :

```
class EnvironmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    egg_list = serializers.CharField(
        widget=widgets.Textarea,
        write_only=True,
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = WebsiteEnvironment
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'modified', 'name', 'url', 'egg_list')
```

And i added a method "validate_egg_list" to validate the sended data to performs some jobs. But when i try to loads the JSON data i've got an error from json like :

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Indeed the JSON data looks like this :

```
{
    u'six': {
        u'url': u'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/',
        u'version': u'1.5.2'
    },
    u'pytz': {
        u'url': u'http://pythonhosted.org/pytz',
        u'version': u'2014.4'
    }
}
```

All the string are prefixed with the unicode symbol u''.

I have searched everywhere in my API and client to find where i did something wrong but i didn't find anything that could cause this.

Does someone have a clue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code for `validate_egg_list` and the code where you load the data?

Comment: Yep, you can see its code in its repository : https://github.com/sveetch/Gestus/blob/master/gestus/rest/serializers.py#L101

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON. That's a Python repr. You cannot use a JSON parser on a Python repr, it's not the same thing.

Comment: Well if it's really a python repr embedded in an unicode string that is received by rest-framework, i don't know how it has happened because like you can see in my code sample, i really send a JSON

Comment: I don't know what your `patch()` method does, but that's not JSON.

Comment: The `patch()` method comes from [nap](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap/blob/master/nap/url.py#L58) it's just a little wrapper around python-requests

Comment: And it's still not returning JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you linked to on [GitHub](https://github.com/sveetch/Gestus/blob/c41034855a08c642342e14979fe348ea54a56a1d/gestus/rest/serializers.py#L110), what you used to print the data in your edit was

```
attrs[source]
```

Given that `attrs` is a dictionary provided by Django REST Framework and `source` is the key you're to use to validate the value of `egg_list`, I can not fathom why Django REST Framework is passing in the representation of the parsed dictionary. This seems at the very least to be a bug. It would seem that Django REST Framework is making assumptions about the data you should be validating, e.g., a simple data type, not a dictionary. If it calls `str()` on all values in `attrs` then that would explain why you're receiving the `repr`.

Comment: It's what i thought also but i was not sure if it was really a bug or if i did something wrong with the client or the api. I will fill a bug issue at Django REST Framework to validate this.